# Taking average reward is not optimal when estimating state value in MDP?

Tags: markov-process, reinforcement-learning

In policy evaluation process in MDPs, the state value function is calculated as $V(s) = E(r+V(s'))$.

Now suppose there are 7 states in an MDP, where state 1 is the start state and state 7 is the terminal state. Some transitions and their rewards according to some policy are shown in the follows:

```
start -> end, reward

1 -> 2, 0
1 -> 3, 10
1 -> 4, 25
2 -> 5, 0
3 -> 5, 0
3 -> 6, 0
4 -> 6, 40
4 -> 6, 20
5 -> 7, 20
5 -> 7, 30
6 -> 7, 10
6 -> 7, 20
```

According to the policy evaluation formula, we can calculate the state value for each state:`42, 25, 20, 45, 25, 15, 0` respecively for state 1-7.

However, I don't think the state values is a good fit for the transitions. If we define loss as

$Loss = (V(s) - (V(s')+r))^2$

which is the loss used when we adopt function approximators for value functions,we will find that such set of state values gives a loss of 1567. However, by simply multiplying each state value by 0.9, it can give a better loss of about 1472. It is reasonable because there are lots of zero rewards in the transitions.

So my question is: what is the objective function that taking the expectation of rewards optimizes? Is there anything wrong in my reasoning above? If we use a function approximator, it will definately underestimate the state values, what is the root cause for this?

Comment: I lost you at "we will find that such set of state values gives a loss of 1567" - are you comparing to some "true" V that you have not shared? Or are you calculating mean or total loss from individual sampled trajectories against the value functions?

Comment: @NeilSlater it is obtained by adding up the loss of each sample trajectories. For example, for the first transition, the loss is: $(42-25-0)^2 = 289$.

Comment: The transition and reward data you have given is clearly not sampled trajectories though, is it supposed to represent the MDP definition, that you are then sampling from?

Comment: Also, are you summing your loss function over the states - i.e. loss for state 1 + loss for state 2 etc? That is probably your error - I will explain why in an answer if so . . .

Comment: @NeilSlater Sorry I didn't quite get you, why do you say the transitions are "clearly not  sampled trajectories"?

Comment: @NeilSlater No, I'm not summing the loss over states, I'm summing loss over transitions. One transition $S, S', r$, one loss.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63594/discussion-between-darkzero-and-neil-slater).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating V(s) and your loss function using the data in slightly different ways. Most importantly your loss function sums loss once per sample transition, whilst V(s) is using the transitions in more complex ratios.

By using the sample transitions to build an MDP and resolve V(s), you will on average have trajectories visiting state 1 always, state 2 $\frac{1}{3}$ of the time, and state 5 $\frac{1}{2}$ of the time. These ratios need to form part of your loss calculation, because if this were a sampled supervised learning dataset, then they would occur with that frequency - if you do this you should find that the values you calculate do indeed minimise a weighted MSE.

More concretely, for a fair comparison between your loss calculation from samples and the state values you have estimated, you should define total loss as:

$$L = \sum_{i=i}^{N} \frac{\rho_{MDP}(s_i)}{\rho_{N}(s_i)} (V(s_i) - (V(s'_i)+r_i))^2$$

Where $\rho_{MDP}(s_i)$ is the expected frequency of steps that start in state $S$ resulting from your MDP reconstruction to calculate $V(s_i)$, and $\rho_{N}(s_i)$ is the observed frequency of that start state in the sample set.

This formula will tend towards the MSE loss that you were expecting to see, as you take larger, more representative sample sizes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but we don't know $p(s'|s)$ as MDPs in the reinforcement learning settings. We have to estimate the values without knowing the transtion possibilities through the samples we got from the policy...and$\rho(s)$ will be unknown either, I'm afraid...

Comment: @DarkZero: That is why I was asking about your table representing some "true" transitions, because it clearly is not a set of complete sample trajectories (there are three start states and four end states). This answer still applies to your case if those are samples, because they are clearly not representative samples. You appear to have calculated the V(s) as though they were fully representative samples (i.e. you have resolved the MDP transitions and effectively have chosen $p(s'|s)$ . . .  if you then go on to calculate loss direct from your transition table, that explains the discrepancy.

Comment: @DarkZero: I realised my original loss formula was a bit off, because I was still focused on how it could be calculated from the MDP view, whilst you are calculating it from the samples. I have corrected it. Notice the ratio, which will tend towards 1 (and the formula tend towards simple MSE loss) when you have  large numbers of representative samples.